# import global variables to local component LESS angular-cli

Tags: angular, less, angular-cli

My folder structure for angular cli is

```
MyApp/
    src
    style/
        page/
            normalize.less
            styles.less
```

and my angular-cli.json contains

```
"app":{
    "styles": [
       "./style/styles.less
    ]
}
```

I am not able to import any of less in component less
example
in component

```
//app/login/login.component.less
@import 'normalize'
@import './normalize'
@import 'style/normalize'
//none of the above works
```

Answer (score 2):

Double check your file path. Your path should be given as below

```
"app":{
    "styles": [
       "./style/page/styles.less
    ]
}
```

Regarding importing normalize,

install normalize.css by `npm i normalize.css` and add it's path to `app[0].styles`

Path might be `../node_modules/normalize.css/normalize.css`. make sure with the node_modules